# Recyclerview isn't updating data properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created grid with **different span size** using Recyclerview. Some cells in the grid have different span sizes. The text inside the cell is getting updated with a List of words. Some cell in the grids are blank (-). They get updated with new word when user clicks on the cell. Basically a keyboard.

The problem here is - When list gets updated with new words, it doesn't update the grid properly.

What I have tried so far -

When I create 10x5 arraylsit it works but anything less than that breaks the grid. why?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar readProgress;
    private TextView enterWord;
    private TriNode root; 

    // Keyboard Code
    private List<String> keysList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String[] keyVal = {
            "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-",
            "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
            "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l",
            "z", ".", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", "del",
            "tts", "space", "send", "done"
    };

    private RVAdapter rvAdapter;
    private String msg = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        root = new TriNode();
        readProgress = findViewById(R.id.readProgress);
        enterWord = findViewById(R.id.enter_word);
        drawKeyboard();
    }
  
    public void drawKeyboard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < keyVal.length; i++) {
            keysList.add(keyVal[i]);
        }
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_view);
        rvAdapter = new RVAdapter(keysList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
        GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 10);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                if (position == 30 ||position == 37 || position == 38 || position == 40 || position == 41) {
                    return 2;
                } else if (position == 39) {
                    return 4;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        });

        rvAdapter.setOnRVItemClickListener(new OnRVItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClickListener(int pos) {
                msg += keysList.get(pos);

                keysList.set(0,"asdf 0");
                keysList.set(1,"asdf 1");
                keysList.set(2,"asdf 2");
                keysList.set(3,"asdf 3");
                keysList.set(4,"asdf 4");
                keysList.set(5,"asdf 5");
                keysList.set(6,"asdf 6");
                keysList.set(7,"asdf 7");
                keysList.set(8,"asdf 8");
                keysList.set(9,"asdf 9");
                rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                enterWord.setText(msg);
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

**Edit:**

So I figured what was causing problem. In my adapter I was setting visibility gone to textview and imageview based on special keys.

```
String title = keyVal[position];
        if(title.equals("del") || title.equals("tts") || title.equals("space") || title.equals("done")){
            holder.titleView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier("key_"+title,"drawable",context.getPackageName()));
        }else{
            holder.titleView.setText(title);
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.titleView.setText(title);
        holder.indexView.setText(String.valueOf(position));
```

Comment: What do you means `breaks the grid`, crash? or positions are wrong?

Comment: @GuanHongHuang No crashes. Just the grid isn't updating all the cells with new words. Some cells remain blank. I tried logging the updated keylist and it gets updated with the new value but gird misses values.

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter, Remove the ArrayList parameter and create a setter function.

RVAdapter.class

```
    ArrayList keysList;

    RVAdapter(Context context) {
    
      ...
    }

    void setKeyList(ArrayList keysList) {

        this.keysList = keysList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Then you can call `rvAdapter.setKeyList(keyList);` when list is changed.

Comment: I have tried this already and it wasn't working either. I figured what problem is but that's the weird one. If you add 0-9 in the original array then it will start populating the grid properly. can you tell me why?

Comment: @BLΛCK do you have GitHub link?